# Why are commits from other pull request in my new pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am fairly new to working in a team with git.

I startet at "origin/master".

[image]

1. First I created a new branch `feature/26062018-offline-seite_ef`.
2. I added commits.
3. I checked out the local `master` branch.
4. I merged in the feature branch (`git merge feature/26062018-offline-seite_ef`)
5. I pushed to the remote server (`git push origin feature/26062018-offline-seite_ef`)
6. I switched to Bitbucket and created the pull request. There is a commit with id `f0ebe14` but I expected `0593ba83`.

[image]

Then I developed something else:

1. First I created a new branch `feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`.
2. I added commits.
3. I checked out the local `master` branch.
4. I merged in the feature branch (`git merge feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`)
5. I pushed to the remote server (`git push origin feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`)
6. I switched to Bitbucket to create the pull request. But this is what I get:

[image]

I expected only the commit 7a52ce3b but instead I get these two.

What is wrong with my git workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it by executing `git reset --hard 6d960676` (reset to origin/master). Then I started over again completly, but this time I did not merged with my local master at all after I developed my feature. I just let the branch open and unconnected to my local master and push.

And everytime before I create a new feature branch, I checkout master first so that the branch is not created at top of the other feature branch.

Problem: I have to checkout the specific branches everytime if I want to see the changes made from the feature, I can't combine the features. As soon as I merge, then the mess starts again...

Answer (score 2):

Note what you did in your steps 3-5 initially:

> 3. I checked out the local `master` branch.
> 4. I merged in the feature branch (`git merge feature/26062018-offline-seite_ef`)
> 5. I pushed to the remote server (`git push origin feature/26062018-offline-seite_ef`)

What you did in step 4 is sometimes called a *test merge*.  You did not push this merge anywhere, but *you still have it in your repository.*

You then proceeded, in your second group of steps, to:

> created a new branch `feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`.

This particular name, at this point in time, named the test merge that you made.  The additional commits you made in step 2 build from this merge, so the commits you pushed in the end were:

- all the commits you made in the first group (they probably already had those via your earlier pull request so that part probably went very fast); plus
- the merge commit; plus
- the commits you made after creating `feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`.

Hence, those are the commits in your *second* pull request: all of the ones in your first, plus the merge, plus the ones you wanted to have in it.

What you should have done was any of the following:

- make the test merge on some *other* branch (not your `master`), or
- make the test merge on `master` but then remove it (`git reset --hard HEAD~1` for instance); or
- don't even bother with the test merge (only good practice in some restricted cases).

What you need to do at this point is retract the second pull request.  You can make a *new* branch starting from the last commit before the first test merge—remember, at this point you have *two* test merges on your `master`.  This starting point will generally also match the commit hash ID of `origin/master`.  Now that you have a new branch, you can use `git cherry-pick` to copy the desired commits to new commits that extend the graph correctly, test-merge the commits if you like, and push *these* commits.  (You can re-use the branch name by renaming the branch that has too many commits, using `git branch -m`; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You created the new branch `feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef` from the `feature/26062018_offline-seite_ef` branch instead of the `master` branch. You thus included the changes from the `feature/26062018_offline-seite_ef` branch into your branch.

Comment: But I checked out master before creating the branch `feature/26062018-newsletter-popup_ef`?! So how should this be possible?